# SQL Server - Selective condition in the select query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables `Companies1` and `Companies2`, where company name always exists in the `Companies2` table, but may or may not be in the `Companies1` table.

I need to apply this condition:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 112) BETWEEN Start AND End
```

only if name exists in `Companies1` table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    COALESCE(NULLIF(Company1_Name, ''), Company2_Name) Company
FROM 
    [Companies1] AS C1 
LEFT JOIN 
    [Companies2] AS C2 ON (C1.Company1_Name = C2.Company2_Name) 
WHERE 
    Company1_Name = ('XYZ') 
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 112) BETWEEN Start AND End
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This is just a logic question - use appropriate AND, OR and brackets and you can do it. I can't quite work out what you're asking but just use logic... and an `EXISTS` clause

Comment: you want to apply that condition for what purpose ? what are you want to achieve ?

Comment: if you change left join to join you'll get rows where [name] exists in [Companies1] table

Comment: only Companies1 Table has Start and End column. So if i query for a company name which exists only in Companies2 then this query fails to fetch the name from Companies2 Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try something like this. **Also Please do not use functions around the columns in the where clause as it makes the query nonsargable.**

```
select DISTINCT COALESCE(NULLIF(Company1_Name,''),Company2_Name) Company
FROM [Companies1] as C1 left join [Companies2] AS C2 
on(C1.Company1_Name=C2.Company2_Name) where Company1_Name=('XYZ') 
AND 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), getdate(), 112) >= 
        CASE WHEN C1.Company1_Name IS NOT NULL THEN [Start] ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), getdate(), 112) END

AND 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), getdate(), 112) <= 
    CASE WHEN C1.Company1_Name IS NOT NULL THEN [End] ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), getdate(), 112) END
```

Comment: if i want to add one more and condition like if(C1.Company1_Name IS NOT NULL) then add one more condition (AND C1.Company_listed = 'Yes') to the existing query.

Comment: something like this worked out for me AND (C1.Company_listed is null or C1.Company_listed=('YES'))

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(NULLIF(Company1_Name,''),Company2_Name) Company
FROM [Companies1] AS C1 LEFT JOIN [Companies2] AS C2 ON (C1.Company1_Name=C2.Company2_Name) WHERE EXISTS Company1_Name=('XYZ') AND 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), getdate(), 112) 
IN BETWEEN Start AND End
```